# How to dis-allow spaces in multiple inputs?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 input fields and I need a short jquery code to disallow spaces in them.

```
<input id='email' type='email' name='email' />
<input id='username' type='text' name='username' />
<input id='pwd' type='password' name='pwd' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, add a class to the 3 `input tags`

```
<input id='email' class='disallow' type='email' name='email' />
<input id='username' class='disallow' type='text' name='username' />
<input id='pwd' class='disallow' type='password' name='pwd' />
```

Here is the jQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.disallow').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 32) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/7YHq9/)

Comment: you have to think like a user.  it was trivial to copy/paste "john doe" into your fiddle and violate the request.  op didn't limit it to "typing spaces"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input').keypress(function (e) {

    // For detecting charCode, the following is the best cross-browser approach
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 32) {

        // the default action of the event will not be triggered.
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This will disallow spaces in all the inputs. If you want to disallow spaces on only three of the inputs above or more, just add a class to all of them like `myClass` and call the function like:

```
$('.myClass').keypress(function (e) {
```

Comment: again, doesn't consider ways that users will often input data. They use more then the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

This is the first solution that the user cannot bypass by pasting in a value from their clipboard -- something user's do a lot of.

This is the first solution that the user cannot bypass because they are using a browser extension to fill out logins/forms for them.

Since you mention jQuery what about form validation with [Validate Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/)?

Or if you want simple validation how about using an submit event to test it.

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var spaceTest = new RegExp('^[^ \t\r\n\v\f]*$');

    //loop through your desired form elements
    $(this).find('.disallow').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            m = spaceTest.exec($this.val());
        // if it fails your test
        if (m === null) {
            // reject

        } else {
           // accept
        }
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/DfkMd/)