# Run jQuery function when a browser's automatically suggested option is clicked

Tags: jquery

My current code changes the color of the input field's border to green if it is a valid email, and to red if it is an invalid email.
html:

```
<input class="ui_input2 no_space" id="input_email" type="email" name="email" style="height:25px; width:300px; font-size:16px;" required />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input_email').keyup(function() {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var val_i_email = $("#input_email").val();

        var empty = false;
        $('#input_email').each(function() {
            if (val_i_email < 5 || !emailReg.test(val_i_email)) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $(this).addClass("invalid");
            $(this).removeClass("valid");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("valid");
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works perfectly when typed but if you clicked on an option (example: previously used email), the border's color does not seem to change unless you edited the text a bit.

Screen shots:
[image]

I clicked the highlighted option above. Here is the result:-

[image]

Is there a way to run another function or the same function again when the automatically  suggested option is clicked?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/7bmrb/)

Comment: what are you going to do if users are submitting your form via lastpass or other extensions that bypass these events?  see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262791/how-to-dis-allow-spaces-in-multiple-inputs/

Answer (score 1):

just use the `oninput` instead of `keyup`

```
 $('#input_email').on('input',function(e){
 ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/7bmrb/3/

> **Note:** The oninput event is supported in Internet Explorer from version
>   9. [more informations](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php)

Comment: If you need to support < IE9, I'd just set up a timer to fire every second or so to check the value of the textbox. Otherwise `oninput` is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `on()` to bind multiple events, to try and cover the range of user-events that register entry:

```
$('#input_email').on('change input paste keyup', function(){
    /* do things here */
});
```

Comment: Do you know best method using multiple binding events to avoid multiple triggering? Just wondering

Comment: I think `oninput` event fire after Cut, delete, or paste content, so there is no multiple triggering between `oninput` and `onpaste` ?

Comment: @Ouadie Thats right but i was wondering the simplest way if e.g paste or keyup has been fired to avoid oninput to be fired too. Could be easily done with a timer but its quite weird.